# How to pop up UIAlertView when the numberofrow (TableView) is 1

Tags: objective-c, uialertview

I have an 'add' button to create new row of tableview. And the number of row is limited to one.

```
    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 1;
}
```

I'd like the button to pop up an alert view when there is one row, not allowing to create a new row.

However i don't know how to implement an 'if condition' in the Button action as following:

```
    - (IBAction)add
{
    if (condition)
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Hi" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Done" otherButtonTitles:nil];
}

    [alert show];
    }
```

Please Help! Sorry for not being professional, I'm trying to learn objective c

Comment: You are returning the number of rows, just use that same calculation when checking if you should show the alert.
However, if you are always returning one for the row count, there's no way the alert could show.

Comment: thanks for telling me, it perfectly makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is -

```
- (IBAction)add
{
  if ([self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0] == 1)
   {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Hi" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Done" otherButtonTitles:nil];
   }

  [alert show];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need have an mutableArray to hold the data of UITableView and return the count of array provide to UITableView through "numberOfRowsInSection" method, when you want to add a row , you just add a data into the Array and reload the tableView.

ps:you can't add row but return 1 to UITableView

Answer (score 0):

Create boolean variable **shouldCreateRow**.

Write the tableview datasource method as

```
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
     if(shouldCreateRow){
      return 1;
    }
}
```

and the action method as

```
- (IBAction)add:(UIButton *)sender {

sender.selected=!sender.selected;

if (sender.selected && !shouldCreateRow) {

    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"One row created" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

    [alert show];

    shouldCreateRow=TRUE;
    [myTable reloadData];

}else{

    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Already there is One row." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

    [alert show];
}
}
```